# SharePoint 2013 timer job run on development server but not on production server of client

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-timer-job

I have developed a custom timer job for SharePoint 2013 in visual studio 2015 which update. The issue is that it works fine on the development server.

I have followed the following steps to debug it on the production server environment of client

1. Deploy the timer job on globally on the farm.
2. Restart the timer service in services.msc
3. Activate feature of timer job to the respective site.
4. Click start now button of timer job
5. Check the history of timer job and its showing in 00:00:00 hours its took to restart.
6. I have checked the Sharepoint log by ULS there is an entry of timer job title is showing as "ABCTimer job is start"
   But it`s not updated data in the destination database.
   I have written various trace logs. However, this trace log also not shown in ULS.

The constructor of the project is as follows:

```
public ABCTimer(SPWebApplication webApp) : base(JobName, webApp, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
{
      this.Title = "ABCTimer";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using powershell commands for deployment..?

Comment: Yes, I have used :1) Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath 

2) Install-SPSolution  -GACDeployment –Force